# Android: Google Maps API still free?

Tags: android, google-maps

I read that google maps will not be free to use for websites in the near future - this brings me to the question if the google maps APIs for android development will still remain free?

Comment: Where did you read this?, also if anyone answers this, you can't take his/her word for it, unless s/he represents Google.

Comment: Here is a blog entry to this:
http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/10/introduction-of-usage-limits-to-maps.html

Even with Philipp Reichart's answer it still isn't clear to me whether the "MAPS API" also includes the "google map lib" that one can use as an app developer for android.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**For [mobile apps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#usage_apis) (Android, iOS), there currently are no quotas:**

> The Google Earth API, and native Maps APIs for mobile platforms such as Android and iOS are not affected. Use of the embed feature of Google Maps, and other Google products that offer an embed feature that includes a map, are not affected by these limits."

For other use cases **(desktop apps, web services, web sites, etc.)**, there is still free quotas to use for Maps, only when you exceed them (and if they are enforced), you'll have to pay.

Please check out the section about [usage limits in the Google Maps API FAQs](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usagelimits) for detailed, up-to-date information and pricing.

From the [Google Geo Developers blog](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/10/introduction-of-usage-limits-to-maps.html):

> However no site exceeding these limits will stop working immediately. We understand that developers need time to evaluate their usage, determine if they are affected, and respond if necessary. There are three options available for sites that are exceeding the limits:
>
> [...]
>
> We will also provide at least 30 days notice on this blog before enforcement of the usage limits and billing for excess usage begins.
>
> [...]
>
> We will then start billing excess usage to your credit card when we begin enforcing the usage limits in early 2012.

Again, please read the full blog post for all the details.

Comment: Actually, as I understand it, Maps API does not relate to the usage of the Maps SDK on iOS and/or Android. (Showing natvie maps on the device) - can you clarify?

Comment: Oh, you seem to be right. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#usage_apis sez: "The Google Earth API, and **native Maps APIs for mobile platforms such as Android and iOS are not affected**. Use of the embed feature of Google Maps, and other Google products that offer an embed feature that includes a map, are not affected by these limits."

Comment: Update the Answer then, once you get of the plane :)