# Google Maps Paid or Free

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play

I am developing a android application which is going to be paid in Android market.
My application is using Google Maps.

For the purpose of using Google Maps in Android Paid Application, Google Maps is still free ?

Comment: Related question: [Google Maps API still free?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951916/android-google-maps-api-still-free)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Google Maps is free to use in any type of application.

Comment: I don't know about 2012, but in 2016 that is not entirely true.  See https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/#details for more information.